# Question eligible for bounty

Tags: support, bounty

I've seen that my question as been flagged "eligible for bounty".

What "mechanism" (if any) select between the questions  the eligible ones ?

Thanks

mauro

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: Thanks. I've understood the basic mechanism of bounty. What is not clear to me is who (if any) has chosen my questions as "eligible for bounty".

Comment: Summary: your question becomes eligible after 2 days.

Answer (score 3):

New questions are initially not eligible for having a bounty placed on them (I believe there are good reasons for this - mostly to do with potential abuse of the close system if there were no eligibility delay). Two days after the question has been posted, it becomes eligible for a bounty. Anyone with high enough reputation (75) can offer a bounty on an eligible question.

Comment: Ok. Now I think I've understood ... my doubt was about the existence of some "hidden committee" selecting between the question entered the "apt" ones to be eligible.